# How can I stop a network drive from mounting on startup - Mac OS X 10.6.2

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, networking, login, mount

Specifically, a network drive that I previously mounted manually for a one-time operation and now tries to re-mount every time I login.

The drive is not setup as a login item in my accounts pref pane, nor has it ever been.

*In response to the comments:*

I don't run any apps from the share. It's a network drive I don't normally use, I just mounted once to get some data of it.

I initially mounted it just by using the 'connect to sever' option in finder.

Comment: What protocol uses your network driver ? (NFS, SMB, etc)
How have you mount it the first time ? (Finder or mount command)

Comment: Did you run any applications from the share?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the questions, I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting place to try and figure out why the computer is trying to mount the share is to check out this previous question on Super User: [Common Mac OS folders/settings to check](https://superuser.com/questions/10958/common-mac-os-folders-settings-to-check-when-trying-to-get-rid-of-a-pesky-self-l) (Question 10958).

It sounds like some program is either trying to read a file from that share, or it's possible that the folder was added to your Login Items. Does this occur with other user accounts on the same computer? If not, it's definitely a setting in your user account, if it does with other accounts it's something set in the system itself.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I haven't been able to find anything conclusive using that list yet, however. I will update you if I manage to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to check...

I had made a shortcut (alias) to a network drive in the Dock to make it easier to connect when I needed it. In at least MacOS Big Sur, the network drive would automatically get mounted at login. Deleting the Dock shortcut stopped the network drive from auto mounting. Not sure if this is a new 'feature', it didn't happen in earlier OS versions.